# Click to reveal answer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, toggleclass

UPDATED to INCLUDE more CODE

Our webdesigner has had a stroke and I've been trying to finalise some of the design in his absence.  It seems he is unlikely to ever be able to help me.

I've been using typepad and one of the pages has FAQs and uses javascript so that if you click on a question the answer is revealed.  Then if you click on the answer text it disappears again.  I updated some of the answer text and it seems to have broken the javascript links somehow.  I've been doing tutorials and trying to learn how to fix it.  It now just shows the questions and answers and the click to reveal functionality has been lost.

Our designer was using onclick = toggle

I have included the  code (replacing the answer text with Answer 1 for brevity) here to see if anyone can point out how it has been broken/how I can fix it.  Sadly I have zero experience of doing this.  Thank you so much :)

```
<p>FAQ Display</p>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
function toggle(Info) {
var CState = document.getElementById(Info);
CState.style.display = (CState.style.display != 'block')
                   ? 'block' : 'none';}
// ]]></script>
<div><strong>Click on the question to reveal the answer!</strong><br /><br /></div>
<h3>Services</h3>
<div class="FAQ" onclick="toggle('faq17')"><strong>Why use this service?   </strong>
<div id="faq17" class="FAA">Answer 17.</div>
</div>
<div class="FAQ" onclick="toggle('faq1')"><strong>How much does the cleaning and labelling service cost?</strong>
<div id="faq1" class="FAA">Answer 1.</div>
</div>
<div class="FAQ" onclick="toggle('faq2')"><strong>How do I book the service?   </strong>
<div id="faq2" class="FAA">Answer 2.</div>
</div>
<div class="FAQ" onclick="toggle('faq3')"><strong>How long does the service take?</strong>
<div id="faq3" class="FAA">Answer 3.</div>
</div>
<div class="FAQ" onclick="toggle('faq4')"><strong>Is there a minimum number of residents required to visit my facility?</strong>
<div id="faq4" class="FAA">Answer 4.</div>
</div>
<h3>DIY Kits</h3>
<div class="FAQ" onclick="toggle('faq5')"><strong>Where can I purchase a kit from?</strong>
<div id="faq5" class="FAA">Answer 5.</div>
</div>
<div class="FAQ" onclick="toggle('faq6')"><strong>How much does a DIY kit cost?</strong>
<div id="faq6" class="FAA">Answer 6.</div>
</div>
<div class="FAQ" onclick="toggle('faq7')"><strong>How long will my kit last?    </strong>
<div id="faq7" class="FAA">Answer 7.</div>
</div>
<div class="FAQ" onclick="toggle('faq8')"><strong>Do the kits expire?</strong>
<div id="faq8" class="FAA">Answer 8.</div>
</div>
<div class="FAQ" onclick="toggle('faq9')"><strong>Is there a material data safety sheet (SDS) for the kits?</strong>
<div id="faq9" class="FAA">Answer 9.&nbsp; <span class="asset  asset-generic at-xid-6a01b7c6f66688970b01bb088843a0970d img-responsive"><a href="http://www.identoz.com.au/files/sds-identoz-denture-marking-sealant-version-1.0.pdf">Download SDS iDentOz Denture Marking Sealant Version 1.0</a>   </span></div>
</div>
<h3>Generic Questions</h3>
<div class="FAQ" onclick="toggle('faq10')"><strong>Where is the label placed on the denture?</strong>
<div id="faq10" class="FAA">Answer 10.</div>
</div>
<div class="FAQ" onclick="toggle('faq11')"><strong>Do you service all areas?   </strong>
<div id="faq11" class="FAA">Answer 11.</div>
</div>
<div class="FAQ" onclick="toggle('faq12')"><strong>How do I make payment?    </strong>
<div id="faq12" class="FAA">Answer 12.</div>
</div>
<div class="FAQ" onclick="toggle('faq13')"><strong>Are our staff police checked?</strong>
<div id="faq13" class="FAA">Answer 13.</div>
</div>
<div class="FAQ" onclick="toggle('faq14')"><strong>Is your work guaranteed?</strong>
<div id="faq14" class="FAA">Answer 14.</div>
</div>
<div class="FAQ" onclick="toggle('faq15')"><strong>Do you repair dentures? </strong>
<div id="faq15" class="FAA">Answer 15.</div>
</div>
<div class="FAQ" onclick="toggle('faq16')"><strong>Do you have insurance?   </strong>
<div id="faq16" class="FAA">Answer 16.</div>
</div>
<p><hr class="at-page-break" /></p>
```

Comment: _"Our webdesigner has had a stroke and I've been trying to finalise some of the design in his absence. It seems he is unlikely to ever be able to help me."_ : That's one morbid statement...

Comment: I know - poor guy.  He needs to put all of his energy into getting better.  such a nice guy too :(

Comment: Can you show the code before you changed anything?

Comment: Sadly I don't have it - I only changed the text not the code - typepad has a rich text formatting option which I used but somehow that must have broken the links (at least that's what typepad told me when I asked them).  I was just changing the price details and removing the name of a distributor we no longer use

Comment: What I've shown is all I have (apart from the code for more of the questions and answers).  I didn't include it cos there's a lot of text in the answers.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if another portion of your code is causing this to break.

I broke this out into a jsfiddle here: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/40dcofxf/)

```
.FAA {
    display:none;
}
```

I just added the style to initially have it hidden. You can toggle with it and let me know if there is additional problems you may be having

To include this on your page you can simply add this line right before the  tag

```
<head>
<!--May have other code here -->
<style>
.FAA { display:none; }
</style>
</head>
```

This may be the simplest way in doing it

Comment: I can try and share all of the code with most of the text removed if that helps?

Comment: What you did - is what I would like it to do I think!

Comment: Thank you - The part that you have done works well but when I added it to my page it still shows all answers and questions together - so I think there must be another break somewhere.

Comment: I don't think it is broken. I think the initial state of the answers are not recognized and therefore it requires a double click? Can you try that and see if it works

Comment: Ah - yes - if I click on it - it will now reveal/hide.  How would I make sure all the answers are hidden at the beginning?  You've been so incredibly helpful - thank you

Comment: How do I include the CSS?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not to shore what you want but this might work for you:

```
<html><head>
<script type="Text/JavaScript"> function displayanswer(){ 
document.getElementById('question').innerHTML = ' //Put answer here'}
</script>

</head><body>
  <h1>Press on the question for answer</h1>
<button onclick="displayanswer"><h2 id="question"> //put your question here </h2></button>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need JavaScript to do this. You can create click-to-reveal-answer elements with plain HTML using `details`.

```css
details {
  margin: 0.3em 0;
}

summary {
  list-style: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<h1>FAQ Display</h1>

<p><strong>Click on the question to reveal the answer!</strong></p>

<h2>Services</h2>
<details>
  <summary>Why use this service?</summary>
  Answer 17.
</details>

<details>
  <summary>How much does the cleaning and labelling service cost?</summary>
  Answer 1.
</details>

<details>
  <summary>How do I book the service?</summary>
  Answer 2.
</details>

<p><hr class="at-page-break" /></p>
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details